# How do I change the pixel perfect scrolling sensitivity in Firefox?

Tags: arch-linux, firefox, mouse, scrolling, mouse-gestures

I am switching from Windows 11 to Arch with i3 on my Laptop. On Windows 11 Firefox had "pixel-perfect" scrolling (scrolling without steppyness) using the mousepad by default, which I find quite pleasant.

I managed to activate it in Arch by adding `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1` to `/etc/environment` (first I tried putting `Exec=env MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1 firefox` in the firefox Desktop entry but that did not work for some reason). However, it is much faster than in Windows and I do not know how to change that. The X scrolling sensitivity seems to be completely independent from the scrolling speed in Firefox now.

In Windows, it seems to have a 1:1-mapping (the page moves the same distance that my fingers move) when I scroll very slowly, but there is some kind of acceleration if I move my fingers faster. How can I achieve something like this in Arch?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've messed with them, but check out the `general.smoothScroll.*` prefs in Firefox's `about:config` page.